# Is it possible to configure an Android install to run a single app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to configure the Android OS to run only a single app?

Basically what I want to do is customize an Android device so that it boots up and runs one application only, and for that application to be switched to the front of the screen automatically. Also, when it gets closed, to be started up and switched to again. Any ideas?

Thanks,
-David

Comment: Essentially you want to use an android device in a "kiosk" mode?

Comment: Android is just linux. So yes

Comment: Yeah jball, basically a friend of mine who isn't too tech savvy really likes those Google Sky Map and wants a device that just runs that on its own... they're not interested in any other apps or any other functionality. So I said I'd find out if it's doable. Sounds like a waste of a device, but there you go...

Comment: The is an old question, but with the release Lollipop there are now more secure ways to implement kiosk devices that are locked down to one app. I outline some here along with pros and cons: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644803/2888763

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method is to get the source of Android and write your own custom ROM of Android as [Octavian wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081264/is-it-possible-to-configure-an-android-install-to-run-a-single-app/4081326#4081326).

Another alternative would be to write a custom home app that, well, isn't really a home app (but replaces the default home app intent).  See [SlideScreen](http://www.androidtapp.com/slidescreen/) as an example of a non-traditional "home" app.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, sounds good - I've not had any experience with customizing ROMs. So replacing the default home app intent sounds like a good way to try. Cheers

Comment: Can anyone tell me that in which file or at what place i need to do changes in AOSP (in 4.0.4)or anything needed to make my app as home application/launcher application.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You have to fetch yourself the source codes for Android and basically create a custom ROM. After applying all desired modifications you bake your ROM and install it to your device.

Pretty much all you need to know about the source and the process of compiling the sources are located at [Android Sources](http://source.android.com/). You can view the source codes from your browser by following this [link](http://android.git.kernel.org/).

Hope it helps you a bit. Good luck.

Comment: So, your advice is to create a Custom ROM, I know how to create a Custom ROM but how to customize it to run only specific one app, that's what I'm trying to figure without luck, any advice ?