# Need suggestions for Android project

Tags: android, android-activity, operating-system

I have been assigned one project of Android, but before taking it I need your advice. I have following low level features

1. I need to hide whole operating system in android and only show my
   application, even device reboot or reset whenever it start it will
   show only my application. There is no way to access internal
   operating system, as App will take whole control.
2. It has one special switch outside device used to turn on/off display
3. It has another switch to access settings of application. only this switch can allow to go app setting. But Operating system in now way can be seen.

Is this possible to be done in Android version 4 as I heard that after Froyo we can’t do this. I have no issue in compiling operating system and putting mine compiled as application is specific for some specific device. Please advice what version is suitable for this.
Please advice me if this can be done in Java or needed more advance c++

Comment: I don't think it's possible. If you can do this _Google_ damn sure hire you.

Comment: Not with android, you can do with your own operating system or embedded systems

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4081423/2811956 check this it may help you

Comment: Well this is why I asked question, I prefer to compile it, so got one reply that I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if your device is rooted.

You have to install your application as a launcher app. 
In manifest file, Please add below intent filer with your MainActivity to make it launcher.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
</intent-filter>
```

remove launcher2.apk and launcher2.odex file from the /system/app folder (Please take a backup of this files before deleting) and reboot your device.

I do it many times with my device and its works perfectly.

Comment: also you have to make sure user can not install other launcher app. if OS find more than 1 launcher app than it will allow all Os app.